# Rules in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The syntax for rules in SQL Server 2005 is given:

```sql
CREATE RULE [ schema_name . ] rule_name 
AS condition_expression
```

Whenever using rule, for example:

```sql
CREATE RULE list_rule
AS 
@list IN ('1389', '0736', '0877');
```

Why are we using a variable like `@list` in it? It doesn't correspond to the table name or anything. 
Is that used for storing the values given in the IN statement or anything else?

I just need an explanation for this. I know that rules are now deprecated but I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are using a rule for?

Comment: the above given example is cut copy from msdn site .rule is used for enforcing constraints right.I have used a rule for primary key in my table .

Comment: Any name or symbol can be used to represent the value when creating the rule, but the first character must be the at sign (@). This line has mentioned in that article also. I think this is an standard way that provided by M-S.

Comment: Just an FYI .... RULES have been marked deprecated in SQL 2005 & later.  They exists, but you are cautioned against using them in new development work.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: It is beneficial to include a reference to your code if it is not your own, gives credit where credit is due (good or bad code).

Comment: `@list` is just a placeholder in order to be able to have a complete expression. You could also write `@foobar` the name doesn't matter.

Comment: @SQLKiwi I just need to understand how it works in our production environment we use sql server 2005 ,so I should understand why it is used and how can make a change when we upgrade

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN

> *condition_expression* includes one variable. The at sign (@) precedes
>   each local variable. The expression refers to the value entered with
>   the UPDATE or INSERT statement. Any name or symbol can be used to
>   represent the value when creating the rule, but the first character
>   must be the at sign (@).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064.aspx

Comment: so the variable is used to hold the values.isn't